# Find a direct way to calculate recursive elements (simple problem with matrices)

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, jordan-normal-form

I nearly solved this question, I just need a hand with the last part since it is a bit confusing.

We are given the recursive sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ like this:

$a_1=1$, $b_1=2$

$a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$

$b_n=3b_{n-1}-a_{n-1}$

We are asked to find a direct way to find $a_n$ and $b_n$

**Here is what I did:**

$\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\b_n \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1}+b_{n-1} \\ 3b_{n-1}-a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1} \\ b_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = ... = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

the problem is that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonlizable. it's jordan form however is $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, so overall, if $B_J$ is a jordan basis:

$(B_J\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}B_J^{-1})^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \end{pmatrix}$

but what now? How can we find $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1}$??

Comment: You lost $B_j$ at the end.

Comment: ah thats right. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, therefore you can use the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Also note that $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Alternatively compute the first few powers by hand, then conjecture (and prove by induction) that $$\forall k\in \mathbb N\left(\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix} 2^k & k2^{k-1}\\0 & 2^k \end{pmatrix}\right).$$